# Java Binary search

Tags: java, binary-search

Trying to perform a binary search on a sorted array of Book objects.

Its not working well, it returns the correct results for some of the objects, but not all.

I went through the loop on paper and it seems that a number can get missed out due to rounding #.5 upwards.

Any ideas how to make this work?

```
Book found = null;
    /*
     * Search at the center of the collection. If the reference is less than that,
     * search in the upper half of the collection, else, search in the lower half.
     * Loop until found else return null.
     */
    int top = numberOfBooks()-1;
    int bottom = 0;
    int middle;
    while (bottom <= top && found == null){
        middle = (bottom + top)/2;
        if (givenRef.compareTo(bookCollection.get(middle).getReference()) == 0) {
            found = bookCollection.get(middle);
        } else if (givenRef.compareTo(bookCollection.get(middle).getReference()) < 0){
            bottom = middle + 1;
        } else if (givenRef.compareTo(bookCollection.get(middle).getReference()) > 0){
            top = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    return found;
```

Comment: I am adding it to a piece of coursework. Only a standard search is required but i wanted to include a binary search too to make it stand out from the crowd a bit

Answer (score 4):

A couple suggestions for you:

- there's no need to keep a `Book` variable. In your loop, just return the book when it's found, and at the end return `null`. And you can also remove the boolean check for the variable in the `while` condition.
- the `middle` variable can be scoped inside the loop, no need to have it live longer.
- you're doing `bookCollection.get(middle).getReference()` three times. Consider creating a variable and then using it.
- the `middle = (bottom + top)/2` is a classic mistake in binary search implementation algorithms. Even Joshua Bloch, who wrote the Java Collection classes, made that error (see [this interesting blog post](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) about it). Instead, use `(bottom+top) >>> 1`, to avoid integer overflow for very large values (you probably wouldn't encounter this error, but it's for the principle).

As for your actual problem statement, rounding would be downwards (integer division), not upwards. To troubleshoot the problem:

- are you sure the `numberOfBooks()` method corresponds to the length of your collection?
- are you sure the `compareTo()` method works as expected for the types you are using (in your code example we do not know what the `getReference()` return type is)
- are you sure your collection is properly sorted according to `getReference()`?
- and finally, are you sure that using `givenRef.compareTo(bookCollection.get(middle).getReference()) < 0` is correct? In standard binary search implementations it would be reversed, e.g. `bookCollection.get(middle).getReference().compareTo(givenRef) < 0`. This might be what donroby mentions, not sure.

In any case, the way to find the error would be to try out different values and see for which the output is correct and for which it isn't, and thus infer what the problem is. You can also use your debugger to help you step through the algorithm, rather than using pencil and paper if you have to run many tests. Even better, as donroby said, write a unit test.

Comment: Im sure it returns the size of the collection, any other ideas why it wont work consistently?

Answer (score 2):

What about Collections.binarySearch()?

Comment: I wanted to write a method myself. Thanks though

Comment: Implementing algorithms yourself is a good way to understand algorithms.  In production code, it's certainly a good idea to use the implementations available in the language or libraries.

Answer (score 0):

All of JRL's suggestions are right, but the actual fail is that your compares are reversed.

I didn't see this immediately myself, but replicating your code into a function (using strings instead of Books), writing a some simple Junit tests and then running them in the debugger made it really obvious.

Write unit tests!

Comment: Another tactic for understanding what's going on is debug prints.  I'd suggest putting in some prints of the middle element or index inside the loop and see if that gives you a clue to where it's going wrong.

That's more or less what I was watching in the debugger...

With the compare reversal and no other change it seems to work fine for strings.

The only other thing I can think of is that this will definitely fail unpredictably if the list is actually not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It turns out i was binary searching my bookCollection arrayList, and NOT the new sroted array i had created - sortedLib.

Silly mistake at my end, but thanks for the input and suggestions!